# Could Zoro challenge shanks?

Tags: one-piece

Zoro wants to be greatest swordsman.Shanks was mihawk greatest rival.Thereby,it shall be possible Zoro end up having a duel with shanks when luffy will get to meet him.

Comment: You're asking us to speculate about future events, and those kinds of questions are off-topic here. Of course he *could*, because whether he actually *will* is impossible to say unless it actually happens (or doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

There is a chance but it might happen to be the case that he will have the same answer as mihawk, to not fight a man with one hand , there is also a speculation of mihawk going to where shanks might be after govt started going after him.